# How to give permission to others to trigger a flow in power automate

Tags: power-automate

I have created a flow in Microsoft Power Automate. When I am using the flow it is Triggering but when my teammate are using it. It is not triggering. Can someone tell me what is the reason for this. Please give some solution to this problem. I am using "when an item is created" trigger

Comment: Are we supposed to read your mind? We need more information, like … what type of trigger are you using?

Comment: I am using when an item is created in list

Comment: So when you say “using it”, what does that mean? Your colleague shouldn’t need to use it, if you have a flow that has a trigger tied to the create/change of an item in a SharePoint list then it will fire regardless of who makes the change.